# Importing model into three.js - performance

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

Is there a good/recommended approach regarding performance to load a 3D model from file to be used in a three.js JavaScript application (especially where the model is generated in Blender)?

I currently have the following workflow:

1. Create model in Blender.
2. Export using the three.js exporter.
3. Load from javascript using `THREE.JSONLoader`

This works great except that the resultant JSON file can be around 4MB and it would be good if I could reduce this size. I am wondering what the best approach is: -

- Minify the JSON file (a bit tricky as most of the js minifiers I have come accross don't seem to work), or
- Use gzip compression (a bit of handshaking required), or
- Use a binary format (I imagine this requires conversion back to JSON) or
- Use OpenCTM format (unfortunately the scripts don't seem to work in Blender 2.70).

I have done some research, representative examples being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706962/746754), [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/openctm/discussion/936560/thread/54661ad7/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473478/compressed-json-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763165/746754). From what I have found the main approaches seem to fall under those I have listed in the bullet points above. Each have some hurdles to overcome.

So, I am asking - is there a good/recommended approach regarding performance to load a model from file?

**Update**

So, it has been a while since I asked this question and I thought I'd report back on the approach I took. In the end I optimised the models, reducing the number of vertices without much loss of visible quality for the size that I am using them for. I also cache on the client in indexeddb as a blob.

Answer (score 4):

I've had some experience with this kind of problem. The issue here is that you model most likely has a lot of points/polygons. So no matter what format you use every point and face of your model has to be described. This ensures a large file size and there is no way around it.

My solution was to look at Blender rather than Three.js and optimise my models. There are a ton of posts on this topic (e.g. [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/27447/how-can-reduce-the-poly-count.html), [here](http://blog.artillery.com/2012/05/reducing-polygon-count-and-file-sizes.html), and [here](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/basic-optimise-models-for-export-to-games.php#where)). After learning more about how Blender works, I was able to reduce most of my 4-8 Mb meshes down to < 200kb each without noticable degradation to the objects rendered in the browser.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I will look at this too. The json file does seem like it compresses quite well, so I will probably end up doing a combination of both.

Comment: Helped me a lot reducing model sizes, this [article](http://blog.artillery.com/2012/05/reducing-polygon-count-and-file-sizes.html) about **Decimation Modifier** was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I saw your comment on my question and I can confirm I used Blender 2.68a. To load from openctm format I did:

```
var loader = new THREE.CTMLoader();
...
loader.load( 'models/basic_model.ctm',  function( geometry, material ){
    // create mesh and position it
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xEEEEEE, shininess: 100, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    // Faces have an orientation that orientation decides which side is which. And the culling removes the backside in normal circumstances

    mesh.position = position;
    mesh.scale.set( 30, 30, 30 );

    // render
    scene.add( mesh );
    render();

    meshes[ 'basic_model' ] = mesh;
}, {} );
```

You need to export from Blender using the openctm export plugin and to include `js-openctm` in your project. Don't remember more details, as I'm working on completely different stuff now.

PS: I'm pretty sure I had to manually load the openctm plugin into Blender for it to work

Comment: +1 Thanks, I will persevere with Blender 2.70 and report back.

Answer (score 2):

With the current Blender Three.js exporter (as of writing this I am referring to the r71 dev version) there are a few things you can do:

- dial down the precision values, the short the float value precision
  the smaller the file
- uncheck `Indent`, this is huge on animation files as it removes white spaces and \n characters
- experiment with using msgpack compression (requires the mspack [package](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender/modules/msgpack) be installed) [msgpack loading example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_msgpack)

at some point, tho, the JSON format may not be the most ideal and maybe other formats will work better for you. As previous posts stated; model optimization goes a long ways too.

Comment: Thanks, worth a look.