# three.js JSON File compression

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I have several working Three.js WebGL web pages. See here: https://lpplmarketwatch.com/3d-contour-examples/

However, the JSON files, which I am hosting from a static ftp server, have file sizes around 4 - 6MB. They are large because there many "vertices" in the JSON object. I can compress the files on my own computer to tar.gz to around 1MB. Is there a way to compress these files and have the user's browser uncompress the file with javascript to be loaded by the Three.js JSONLoader?

Comment: you can unzip them in js, just download the zip as a blob and unpack into json.

Comment: you can pass the files using gzip

Comment: I recommend minifying and gzipping the JSON files. That should hopefully be enough.

Comment: ok, so there is a solution with js code by creating a blob and unzipping this blob? Nothing to do with the server (which is a MaxCDN static zone)? I feel like the server should be sending the json compressed, but perhaps I need an http request for a gzip: true?? My settings on the static zone are selected to compress content as gzip. And one of the file types that MaxCDN says it supports is application/json. But when I load the page and look at the developer tools (network) it doesn't seem to be sending a compressed file.

Comment: My question is similar to the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073947/importing-model-into-three-js-performance but I am not using Blender.

Comment: Ok, I think my question was actually not necessary. Although I learned alot about javascript in the process, I just realized that MaxCDN was automatically compressing my files with gzip to a reasonable 69% compression. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

> **WARNING: The JSON library changed at some point so I don't know how well this will work outside of Python 3.**

So one thing I will mention is maybe write your own script to handle re-serializing the JSON and limiting the floating point precision. JSON will go up to 16 decimal place precision and that will hurt you on file size. For the Blender exporter I hacked my JSON library to handle this. Refer to the source here (it's ugly). One may be able to refactor that to work as a standalone outside of Blender.

JSON hack:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/exporter/_json.py

`dump()` implementation for Blender exporter
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/exporter/io.py#L17